# .net core 3.1 upgrade : DataContract and DataMember - unable to hide a field

Tags: swagger, wcf-binding, datacontract, asp.net-core-3.1, datamember

I have a class with

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Id{get; set;}

   //calculated field 
   public int Salary{get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public int Name{get; set;}

}
```

I was able to hide field "Salary" by not having the [DataMember] attribute. Is there a way I could hide/not expose that field in the request?

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeeDetailResponse
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Id{get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public string Grade{get; set;}

   //Used while calculating grade and should be hidden
   public int Salary{get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public int Name{get; set;}

}
```

expected output : I will would like to use the Request as:

Request:

```
Id
Name
```

and Response as

```
Id
Grade
Name
```

Actual output is: 
Request:

```
Id
Salary (Not hidden)
Name
```

and Response as

```
Id
Grade
Salary (Not hidden)
Name
```

I'm testing this using swagger and expect to see only Id and Name in the request and when I enter the input values and execute, I would like to see Id, Grade and Name in the Response. Swagger is displaying Salary with its value. This is happening after upgrading to .net core 3.1. I expect Salary field not to be serialised and should not be exposed in the response

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have updated the question -  It is not hiding Salary and I'm able to see them in the response

Comment: @HenkHolterman    I'm testing this using swagger and expect to see only Id and Name in the request and when I enter those values and execute, I would like to see Id, Grade and Name in the Response. It is displaying Salary with its value as well. This is happening after upgrading to .net core 3.1. I expect Salary field not to be serialised and should not be exposed in the response

Answer (score 1):

Use `[JsonIgnore]` from `System.Text.Json.Serialization` to hide fields from serialization/Swagger.

As best as I can tell, DataContract/DataMember is ignored completely.